# Cucumber-Java: Avoid multiple Logins and use same session for multiple independent scenarios

Tags: cucumber-java

I am running multiple scenarios in a Feature file. Each scenario is a small functional part of the feature.

I am trying to run the scenarios in a way that, Login to the application only once, run all the scenarios in the feature file and after executing last scenario, logout the session.

Tried using Login in Background, but Login is getting called for for every scenario.

Is it feasible using Cucumber, Selenium, TestNG and Java?

Please suggest.

Comment: That would depend on how are you initializing your driver? (i am assuming you are using webdriver) - can you post the code of your driver initialization and where it is being done.  And to your question, yes it is possible but that would depend on the answer to the previous question.

Comment: Thanks niharika,
Driver initialization is done in the webhooks class in @Before hook by calling Driver factory class method.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a specific tag, eg. @ContinueTest.  In your before hooks, negate this tag. say @Before("~@ContinueTest").  This way the open browser will be reused.